# Issue while generating IPA using Xcode 6.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]

While trying to generate IPA for testing purposes, I receive a message:

> "You have a valid iOS Distribution certificate in the Member Center, but it is not installed locally. If your signing identity is installed on another Mac, you export developer profile on that Mac and import it on this Mac. You can revoke current certificate and request a new one."

Why is this happening?

Comment: Hey.. try to install these certificate on your mac or in keyChain.

Comment: i have already does that. same error still @AshokLondhe

Comment: Try to use the last official release of Xcode, not beta version. Check your build settings, you should to use valid ad hoc provision and certificate.

Comment: @bLacKhoLE problem is that you have created certificated and signing identity on another machine and you are using that on another machine.

Comment: @bLacKhoLE that is not the problem of Xcode version .

Comment: but i have created certificate using keychain and create new profile using that cer file on this mac.  @AshokLondhe

Comment: if you have done on same machine then it never given error message like you get.

Comment: i thing its bug from this xcode version, by the way please suggest me if you have any idea to resolve this problem. @AshokLondhe

Comment: Actually i have done this before 3-4 days on Xcode 6.3.1 but not getting any issue..

Comment: i just didn't create new AppID , but other thing i have done on this mac. @AshokLondhe

Comment: So please create app id and try it....

Comment: should i have to use AdHoc or  Development or Distribution certificate for export IPA, right now i am doing with AdHoc @AshokLondhe

Comment: use AdHoc or distribution.

Comment: but,  i have AppID with same bundle ID as per  my Xcode Project. is it required to create new AppID ? @AshokLondhe

Comment: i don't have idea but i think you can create new and try it.

Comment: @bLacKhoLE di you manage to solve this? I have the same issue: after updating xcode i can't export for enterprise or adhoc. Before updating everything worked fine.

Comment: @OmidHashemi If you have P12 certificate or able to generate one  and install it will resolve, Else you have to create new AppID , Certificate and Disctribution Profile (i resolved with second option) .

Comment: @bLacKhoLE thanks, that was my way too!

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me.

On my machine I kept both Xcode 5 and Xcode 6 .

From Xcode 6 beta, Archive the project. Close Xcode 6.

Open Xcode 5, go to Organizer and export as Ad Hoc build with proper provisioning profile.

That's it!

Comment: i want do with xcode 6 , if you have any suggestion on it please let me know, i have already show your this post before.

Answer (score 2):

Majority of these problems are very easily solvable by [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/). In no way I want to promote a product - it's an open-source tool and saved me hell lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

It was Xcode bug.

When I tried to export developer profile from another system and installed in my system its working fine.

Comment: thanks for answer but , will you please show legal statement  By apple. @jaico varghese

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

1. created new CSR (code signing request)
2. created new Distribution certificate with the CSR, once created go download and double click to install
3. create a app id if you dont already have one
4. create your distribution provisioning profile, select your app id and certificate you created
5. after you create it, go download, and double click to install
6. restart xcode

Answer (score 0):

Go to Keychain Access

1. Keychain>Certificate Assistant> Request a Certificate from     Certificate Authority.
2. Fill in the email. (keep others as default values)
3. Save the file.

Log in to Apple Member Center

1. Go to Certificate, profiles Provisioning Profiles
2. Click on Add button on top Right corner
3. Select App ID from the dropdown
4. Select the profile you wish to include.
5. Click on Generate and
6. Download the Distribution certificate

Open keychain Access

1. Go to file>Import Items
2. Select the Distribution certificate.

It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

in my case everything was done as per the manual (I'm experienced in this stuff) but it turns out xcode was acting out.
I used the *user local signing assets* and I was done :)

[image]